# ADF - XML Document from a Table to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to move the XML documents stored in SQL Server Table as an XML column to Azure Blob Storage. I haven't done something like this in ADF. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more details like sample input data, your approach in the question?

Comment: Each row in a table has a unique XML stored in the XML column ... the goal is to save the XML in that column in Azure Blob storage as abc.xml.  Basically moving XML out of the table and stores it at Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: What is the limitation?

Comment: The XML format is not kept as it was in an XML document.

Comment: XML format is not supported in ADF as **sink**. Refer Microsoft links [Azure Data Factory - XML Format Sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/177258/azure-data-factory-xml-format-sink.html), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml

Answer (score 0):

In this repro, I have created a sample table of two records which has xml data. I have copied each XML record into Blob storage file (For every one xml record of SQL table, one file is created in Blob).

- A table is created with the following script in SQL server.

```
drop table if exists XmlValuesTable;
CREATE TABLE XmlValuesTable (pkid varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, v XML NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO XmlValuesTable 
VALUES ('a1','<note><float>123.456</float><time>01:23:45.789</time></note>');
INSERT INTO XmlValuesTable 
VALUES ('b1','<note><float>4.0000000000</float><time>01:23:45Z</time></note>');
```

[image]

- In ADF pipeline, Lookup activity is taken and Query is given as `select pkid from XmlValuesTable`[image]
- Then Foreach activity is added and in settings, `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` is given in **items** text box.
  [image]
- Inside the Foreach activity, copy activity is added. In source Query is given as `select v from XmlValuesTable where pkid='@{item().pkid}'`

[image]

[image]

- In sink activity csv dataset is added and primary key column name pkid is given as filename.
  [image]
- Once pipeline is run, files are created in blob storage.

[image]

**Output:**

**File A1**

[image]

**File B1**

[image]

In this way, We can copy the XML data stored in SQL server to Blob storage.

Comment: amazing and thank you very much. Apart from limitation this solution works.